# shift an element of nav bar to left most side

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have the following Nav bar. I want to shift the Login/Register Component of it on the very left most of the nav bar but can't find a way to do it. What might be the possible solution, I have tried the padding-left:0 thing on the login li element but this does not seem to work. Any help in this would be appreciated

**HTML:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-image: url('bg.jpeg');
}

header {
  background: #d9c2ac;
  position: relative;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:hover {}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #444;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

form .form {
  float: right;
}

.search-bar {
  float: right;
}

ul li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container" id="#home">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="login"> <a href="#login" style="text-align: left;"> Login/Register </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Services </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#Products"> Products </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#contact"> Contact Us </a></li>
          <li>
            <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

[image: Navbar]

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo css to align item.

```
nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y3o2zu65/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**Use rm-auto to set  the margin right to 0**

```css
.navbar-tan
{
  background-color:tan;
}
```

```html
<html>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-tan" >
  <ul class="navbar-nav  mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login/Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    
      <li class="nav-item">
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** here...and use `margin` utilities to align the first and last item...

...apply `margin-right:auto` to the first element to align it left most corner

...and apply `margin-left:auto` to the last element to align it right most corner..

I have also changed your some css and also removed all the `float` values. Also no need to use `position:absolute` here for the search-box.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-image: url('bg.jpeg');
}

header {
  background: #d9c2ac;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: verdana;
}

nav a:hover {}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #444;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container" id="#home">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li id="login"> <a href="#login" style="text-align: left;"> Login/Register </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
        <li>
          <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```